# How to install Quantum GIS Lisboa and scipy

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation

I'm trying to install some plugins of the QGIS but an error occurs. The program asks the scipy program. I installed Python, the Numpy and scipy. Also installed the program R. However, QGIS continues asking for scipy. Could you help me?

Comment: Which OS? How did you install QGIS? Be as specific as you can.

Comment: If your're talking about the LecoS plugin and use Windows then you could follow this tutorial i wrote http://conservationecology.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/24072013_howtoinstallscipyforqgis.pdf